# Como convierto una fecha almacenada en una tabla MySQL almacenada como VARCHAR

Tags: php, mysql

La fecha almacenada en un campo de la tabla en cuestion tiene el formato ('Y-d-m H:m:s') => ejemplo: '2019-25-11 07:32:45', no es una fecha unica, todas varian de acuerdo a la linea de la tabla y debo convertir al formato ('Y-m-d'), donde cambio el dia por el mes y viceversa, ademas de eliminar la hora. Este es mi codigo   y lo que hace es devolver la resta del año menos el mes y el dia...

```
<?php
    $originalDate = date_format(date_create('2019-25-11 09:25:07'), 'Y-d-m H:i:s');

    $originalDate = '2019-25-11 09:25:07';
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-m', $originalDate);


    $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));

    echo "ORIGINAL: ".$date." Nueva ==> ".$newDate."<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas usar PHP, usa [MySQL DATE() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date.asp)

```sql
Select date(your_column), date('2019-11-20 12:12:12')
```

**Update 20191118:**

Basado en tu ultimo comentario, puedes usar la función [STR_TO_DATE de MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/) para convertir un string en un objeto fecha de esta manera:

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2019-21-11','%Y-%d-%m');
```

Comment: El problema es que no lo puedo hacer ya que esta almacenada como  VARCHAR y no como DATE, por otro lado, no es una fecha unica, son miles diferentes, yo puse simplemente un ejemplo

Comment: Asumo que el -1 fue tuyo, quisiera saber por qué. La función date() de MySQL también trabaja con strings y según tu pregunta ya tiene el formato esperado así que no veo por qué no serviría, a menos que hayas omitido algo importante en tu pregunta

Comment: La parte de no es una fecha única no es clara, podrías agregar eso a la pregunta

Comment: Uhh Edgar, te pido mil disculpas, recien veo lo del -1, ni me di cuenta, de seguro fue sin quererlo, todo lo contrario, agradezco la ilustracióon, pero viendo el enlace de MySQL DATE(), no comprendo como es que pueda intercambiar el dia con el mes... si puedes ser mas especifico. Gracias

Comment: @RicardoPastuszek acabo de agregar un update a la respuesta, por favor verifica si es de ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función de php `explode()` para separar strings por un carácter. Esta función retornará en un array los valores separados, lo que hace muy manejable la respuesta de la función.

Primero necesitaremos separar la fecha de la hora y luego los valores de la fecha para así armarlos nuevamente a gusto.

Te dejo un ejemplo para obtener el **timestamp** y desde ahí puedes formatear la fecha como más te guste.

*Siempre que trabajes con fechas recuerda configurar la zona horaria, o tendrás diferencias de horas :)*

```
$original = '2019-25-11 09:25:07';
$date = explode(" ",$original);
$separated_date = explode("-", $date[0]);
$date_formated = $separated_date[1] ."-" . $separated_date[2]. "-" . $separated_date[0];
$final_date = $date_formated . " " .$date[1]; 
$timestamp = strtotime($final_date);
print_r($timestamp);
```